# Getting NaN when using R::runif in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

To generate standard uniform random numbers with Rcpp, I always used

`Rcpp::runif(1, 0, 1)[0]`

The `[0]` is due to `Rcpp::runif` returning *vectors*. I recently found that you can also use the R API and use `R::runif()` instead if you only want a scalar so I can avoid using this `[0]`. I tried this out, but I always get `nan`'s. Here is a small example, the `.cpp` file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double unif_R() {
  const double u = R::runif(1, 0);
  Rcout << "u: " << u << "\n";
  return u;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double unif_Rcpp() {
  const double u = Rcpp::runif(1, 0, 1)[0];
  Rcout << "u: " << u << "\n";
  return u;
}
```

The `unif_R()` function uses `R::runif(a,b)` that returns a scalar, while `unif_Rcpp()` uses `Rcpp::runif(n, a, b)`, which returns a vector. However, when I call these in R using:

```
sourceCpp('runif_test.cpp')
set.seed(21)
unif_R()

set.seed(21)
unif_Rcpp()

set.seed(21)
runif(1)
```

I get the following output:

```
> set.seed(21)
> unif_R()
u: nan
[1] NaN
```

```
> set.seed(21)
> unif_Rcpp()
u: 0.786115
[1] 0.7861149
```

```
> set.seed(21)
> runif(1)
[1] 0.7861149
```

Clearly `unif_Rcpp\ works, but why does` unif_R\ give me `nan`'s?

Comment: @user20650 sorry - this was such a dumb mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @user20650, I made a silly mistake and that I need b >= a. So the correct code should've been:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double unif_R() {
  const double u = R::runif(0, 1);
  Rcout << "u: " << u << "\n";
  return u;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double unif_Rcpp() {
  const double u = Rcpp::runif(1, 0, 1)[0];
  Rcout << "u: " << u << "\n";
  return u;
}
```

And this is fine.